# Impossible to select script line on mobile fone

Tags: text-selection

On any mobile fone running Android, it is impossible to select the whole script line. If you slowly try to move the line to expose more of the script line and then attempt to move the blue end mark of selection to select more of it, it will select everything else in the thread at the top. Is there any other way to select a script line?

[image]

Here everything gets selected. And the *Select All* option will select everything in the post. It is impossible to select the line.

[image]

Comment: If you are referring to the StackOverflow site, I would try the 'Desktop site' option in the browser to see if that helps as markup format code seems to behave as described when rendering into a horizontal scroll region for lengthy code lines.

Comment: thanks! at stackexchange. i also realized i can go into edit post and then easily copy it there. xd